# Java printing Integer Vs Integer.toHexString() : Different outputs

Tags: java, hex, byte, bit-manipulation, bit

I am missing something while determining how Java stores and retrieves integers. I have the following code

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int a = 100;

        int negateA = (a | 0x80000000);

        System.out.println("Negative A: " + negateA);
        System.out.println("Negative A in HEX: " + Integer.toHexString(negateA));

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Negative A: -2147483548
Negative A in HEX: 80000064
```

From the output, the value in HEX makes sense to me as I am setting the most significant bit of the integer and the rest of the value indicates its decimal value to be 100 which is what I 've set it initially.

I fail to understand why when I print just the integer I get `-2147483548`

Is there a difference between how java stores the number internally and when its retrieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you obtain a negative number from a positive number! Java uses [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

In order to invert the sign of an `int` (whether it is initally positive or negative), you do:

```
~val + 1
```

Same for `long`s, `byte`s and `short`s.

The only number for which it doesn't work is 0x80000000, ie `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, ie -2^31. But that is one of the characteristics of an n-bit two's complement representation: it can represent numbers ranging from -2^(n-1) up to 2^(n-1) - 1.

Let's take 1 as an example:

```
0x00000001 // i = 1
0xFFFFFFFE // ~i
0xFFFFFFFF // ~i + 1 == -1

0xFFFFFFFF // i = -1
0x00000000 // ~i
0x00000001 // ~i + 1 == 1
```

Comment: Indeed `System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(-100));` is ffffff9c.

Comment: toHexString() simply dumps the bytes as an unsigned value, but for integers if the signed bit is set it tries to decode it in two's complement. Thanks for helping me understand.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is not between "how it is stored" and "when it is retrieved", but it boils down to how the internal representation is interpreted when you convert to decimal and binary. In the first case it is interpreted as twos-complement, which yields your negative number. When you convert it to hex using Integer.toHexString, it is intepreted as an unsigned value. From the javadoc of Integer.toHexString:

> The unsigned integer value is the argument plus 23^2 if the argument is
>   negative; otherwise, it is equal to the argument

Comment: How its stored is important as there is the line `int negateA = (a | 0x80000000);` directly manipulating the internal representation. While for the purposes of explanation the Javadoc is explained in that way. What really Interger.toHexString() is doing is displaying the actual bytes of used for the internal storage. Integers are encoded in 2's complement form.

Comment: I wasn't saying that internal representation is not Important, I even mentioned two's complement. What I was saying is that printing the integer by implicitely converting it to a string an by toHexString are two different interpretations of the same bit pattern.